# App crashes when spinner is opened on press of home/recent button

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I have a spinner on my application that causes the application to crash when the spinner is opened and then the home or the recent button is pressed

The searchable spinner that is being used is https://github.com/miteshpithadiya/SearchableSpinner

This the error that I am getting been troubling me for quite a while

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.ioksupervisor.ats, PID: 8972
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value Select Material
        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1781)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeList(Parcel.java:934)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1728)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:846)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1542)
        at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1232)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:886)
        at android.app.FragmentState.writeToParcel(FragmentState.java:120)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedArray(Parcel.java:1471)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerState.writeToParcel(FragmentManager.java:599)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1800)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1706)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:846)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1542)
        at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1232)
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.activityStopped(IActivityManager.java:4687)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:4031)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6626)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
```

Populating the spinner

```
    public void populateSpinner(HashMap<Integer, String> map) {

        List<StringWithTag> arrayList = new ArrayList<StringWithTag>();
        arrayList.add(new StringWithTag("Select Material", 0));

// Hash map contains the key-value pair of the options of the spinner
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            Integer key = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(entry.getKey()));
            String value = entry.getValue();
            arrayList.add(new StringWithTag(value, key));
        }

        ArrayAdapter<StringWithTag> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<StringWithTag>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayList);
        arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    }
```

String with tag class

```
public class StringWithTag {

    public String string;
    public Object tag;

    public StringWithTag(String string, Object tag) {
        this.string = string;
        this.tag = tag;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return string;
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Just a guess but try to implement serializable for StringWithTag once.

Comment: post your StringWithTag class too.

Comment: Try to use RecyclerView and your StringWithTag class have issue when are creating Parcable object of StringWithTag.

Comment: I am not sure how to go abut with RecyclerView. any reference code would be helpful

Comment: Default array adapter uses ArrayList<String>. you are passing list of custom model class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After implementing Serializable to StringWithTag still, give me another error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.ioksupervisor.ats, PID: 21320
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner)
```

This was solved by extending and creating a custom searchable spinner. The link of which is https://github.com/miteshpithadiya/SearchableSpinner/issues/55#issuecomment-362430652